# Quick fix of air in clutch line

Tags: clutch, mazda

I drive a 1990 Mazda B2600 2W drive and within the last couple weeks I've noticed that I have been having some problems with my clutch. The clutch goes down to floor and stays there, it feels very soft and I can only get the truck into gear when the car is turned off. It sounds to me like some air got into the clutch line. I plan on fixing it but I need to get the truck back to my house and I was wondering if anyone new of a quick fix for this just enough that I can get it back home?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the clutch master or slave cylinder is leaking. Depending on how long you need to drive it for to get home, it is possible to start in gear and then shift without using clutch (matching RPM). It isn't easy, hard on your synchronizers and any fine maneuvering would be out of question, however should be okay for a bit of highway driving.